# When calling the function with while loop 2 times, it does not delete the first one from memory

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

There is a function that has a while loop. int takes a variable. for example I initialized the function with 4. Then I want to initialize the function with 16.

```
void Widget::on_fourCameras_clicked(){
    CamerasInitialize(4);
}

void Widget::on_sixteenCameras_clicked(){
    isNewCameraSelected = true;
    CamerasInitialize(16);
}
```

When I call it with 16, it does not delete the function I started with the previous 4 from memory. I'm trying to break the previous loop by putting the flag and start the 2nd one. This time, since the click function does not change the flag before it ends, it starts the function I sent 16 first. Then it changes the flag. I can't do it in multithread because of the functions I use. What do I need to do to repeatedly call the same function with a while loop and delete the previous ones from memory?

ubuntu 20.04.02
QT / c++

```
void Widget::CamerasInitialize(int camNumber) {

    namedWindow( "Output", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL );
    setWindowProperty( "Output", WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );

    cv::cuda::GpuMat *inputFrames = new cv::cuda::GpuMat[camNumber];
    cv::cuda::GpuMat *inputFramesConverted = new cv::cuda::GpuMat[camNumber];
    cv::cuda::GpuMat *sphericalDistortionOutput = new cv::cuda::GpuMat[camNumber];
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> videoReader[camNumber];
    cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<int32_t> *d_ptrs = NULL;
    cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<int32_t> *h_ptrs = new cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<int32_t>[camNumber];

    cudaMalloc(&d_ptrs, camNumber * sizeof(cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<int32_t>));

    std::time_t timeBegin = std::time(0);
    int tick = 0;
    long frameCounter = 0;

    setCurrentMatrixCpuToGpu(camNumber);

    while (true)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<camNumber; i++){
            videoReader[i]->nextFrame(inputFrames[i]);
            h_ptrs[i] = inputFrames[i];
        }

        if(isMovedCamera){
            pBackSub.release();
            pBackSub = cuda::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG();
            isMovedCamera = false;
        }

        cudaMemcpy(d_ptrs, h_ptrs, camNumber * sizeof(cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<int32_t>), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        GpuMat outval;
        Mat outputCPU;

        if(camNumber == 4){
            arrayMult(d_ptrs, outval, cameraMatrixOnGpu4Camera, pixelW, pixelH);
        }else if(camNumber == 16){
            arrayMult(d_ptrs, outval, cameraMatrixOnGpu16Camera, pixelW, pixelH);
        }

        //cuda::bilateralFilter(videoFrames[0], colorImages[0], 90, 30, 30);
        frameCounter++;

        std::time_t timeNow = std::time(0) - timeBegin;

        if (timeNow - tick >= 1)
        {
            tick++;
            //cout << "Frames per second: " << frameCounter << endl;
            frameCounter = 0;
        }

        outval = outval(Rect(cropPositionsX, cropPositionsY, cropPositionsW, cropPositionsH));
        cuda::resize(outval, outval, Size(SCREENRESOLUTION_WITDH, SCREENRESOLUTION_HEIGHT), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);

        imshow( "Output", outval);

        setMouseCallback("Output", CallBackFunc, NULL);

        if (waitKey(1) == 'q' || isNewCameraSelected)
        {
            isNewCameraSelected = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //destroyWindow("Output");
}
```

Comment: QT has a single UI thread. Your first call to CamerasInitialize() will block any further UI interaction until it has finished. Your second click handler will not even be called until it has finished. You need to use threads.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I have a problem with opencv imshow when I use thread. That's why I'm trying to handle this thread. Maybe I should use functions differently. I'm not sure

Comment: If you must use the UI thread then you may be able to use processEvents() or similar inside your while loop. See https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer i will review this. thank you